# PM give me ERROR: Type is not resolved for member..on any migration command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I was run a downloaded application from the internet. If I used migration in PM console, I got this error.
 I spent a lot of time searching for a solution.

I found Microsoft's reference of common errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/data/jj618307.aspx

it say

**ERROR:** Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

**NOTICE:** This error can be caused by specifying an incorrect startup directory. This must be the location of migrate.exe

Answer (score 4):

solution: check your application (directory) path if not contains **&**, because it is reserved and throw this error.
I copied my application to another path and its working fine.
This post probably can help and save time to someone, who has same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its  possible that you have changed the project name folder with a different name, and now that cause that error to occur. I renamed the project folder and this error started coming up, and I put it back to its original name and it resolved this issue